# How to construct a basis for the dual space of an infinite dimensional vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional vector space over a field $K$. Then it is known that $\dim V < \dim V^*$. More precisely, by a result attributed to Kaplansky and Erdos, we have $\dim V^* = |K|^{\dim V}$.

I have not seen an actual construction of a basis of $V^*$. My question is: given a basis $B$ of $V$, is there an explicit description of a basis of $V^*$ in terms of $B$? Can you do this at least in the case where $\dim V$ is countable?

Comment: $K^B$ (maps from $B$ to $K$).

Comment: You cannot do this "explicitly": it requires some form of the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is consistent with the axioms of $\sf ZF$ that this is impossible. Specifically, if you consider $\Bbb R[x]$, then its dual space is just $\Bbb{R^N}$. And it is consistent with $\sf ZF$ that $\Bbb{R^N}$ does not have a Hamel basis.

(Under $\sf ZF+DC$, if all sets are Lebesgue measurable, or have the Baire property, then every group homomorphism between Polish groups is continuous. It follows that if $\Bbb{R^N}$ has a basis, then there is a discontinuous functional from $\Bbb{R^N}$ to $\Bbb R$ simply by cardinality arguments. And therefore such theories prove that $\Bbb{R^N}$ does not have a Hamel basis.)

It follows that there is no explicit way to specify how you get a basis of the dual space. You have to appeal to Zorn's lemma.

Comment: Out of interest, can you give a reference and/or sketch proof for this consistency result?

Comment: Of course I can.

Comment: I was reading your comment just before you edited it, I thought you were waiting  Peter asks you for for giving the reference/sketch, of course you can!!!

Comment: @Rahman: Unfortunately, that's all to typical for me to do. Nonetheless, it wasn't what I was doing at this time! :)

Comment: I would be happy to learn more about the downvote!

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I suppose then that same is true for all other fields and infinite dimensions?

Comment: @spin: Well, not exactly. Here we use the fact that we have a topological vector space and a topological field. Over an arbitrary field, it's going to play differently. But there's no general way to construct a basis for a dual space, that's the important part.

Comment: @spin It is consistent (with ZF + non-AC) that there is a vector space with an infinite basis (but I hesitate to call it infinite-dimensional) such that $V^*$ has an explicit basis: Let $B$ be amorphous, $V$ a vector space with basis $B$.  For simplicity: over $K=\{0,1\}$. - Let $\chi_b:B\to K$ be the characteristic function of $\{b\}$, and let $\chi_\infty:B\to K$ be constant with value $1$. Extend these functions linearly to all of $V$, then $(\chi_b:b\in B\cup \{\infty\})$ is a basis of $V^*$, I think.

Comment: @Martin: That is correct. And the hesitation is understandable. "Not finite dimensional" is my goto term.